# Delete files from directory using maximum number

Tags: php

I have the following codes/photos for my products:

```
D2000-1.jpg
D2000-2.jpg
D2000-3.jpg

D2001-1.jpg
D2001-2.jpg
D2001-3.jpg
D2001-4.jpg
```

I want to delete everything after -1.jpg photo of product D2000 and -2.jpg photo of product D2001, and to remain only:

```
D2000-1.jpg
D2001-1.jpg
D2001-2.jpg
```

Is this possible with PHP? I want to do this, because I have thousands of product photos to delete.

**EDIT:**

Here's what I've done for now:

```
<?php
// Maxmimum photos
$codes = array(
    'D2000' => '1',
    'D2001' => '2',
);

// Directory listing
$files = scandir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/products');
natsort($files);

// Process deletion
foreach($codes as $code => $photo) {
    //
}
?>
```

Comment: give e.g. for D2002 and D2003 also to make it clear wat u wat to achieve

Comment: Give clarity to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your foreach:

```
$processed = array();

foreach($files as $f){
    $n = basename($f, '.jpg');
    $d = explode('-', $n);
    $processed[$d[0]][] = $d[1];
}

foreach($codes as $name=>$max){
    while(isset($processed[$name][$max-1])){
        $suffix = array_pop($processed[$name]);
        unlink($name.'-'.$suffix);
    }
}
```

Should work, didn't test.

Comment: Excellent! I just changed $max-1 to $max and $suffix to $suffix.'.jpg' :-)) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you ready solution but some pseudo (unverified) code.

```
// we will get DXXXX and number after '-' separately for every photo name.
$names = array_map(function($file) {
  //get only file without extension
  $fileName = explode('.', $file);
  //separate e.g. D2000 and 1
  return explode('-', $fileName[0]);
},$files);

//you should iterate files, not codes
foreach($files as $file) {
  //if this photo not in $codes, don't do anything
  if(!in_array($file[0], $codes)) { continue; }
  //if number of photo > threshold, then delete
  if($file[1]> $codes[$file[0]) {
    unlink($file[0].$file[1].'.jpg');
  }

}
```

It should give you a shape off what you're looking for.